# I have a recursion function issue?

Tags: java, function, recursion

This is my first recursion problem and I'm not understanding it, nor does it work. Any ideas?

```
int C;
        int myFactorial;

        int n = Integer.parseInt(objectsChooseField.getText());
        int r = Integer.parseInt(chooseFromField.getText());

        if (C == 1){
           return 1; 
        }
        return (C*(myFactionial(n!/(r!(n-r)))));
        //C(n,r) = n!/(r!(n-r));    
    }
```

Comment: No recursion here. Some code is missing

Comment: Where exactly is the recursion?

Comment: Your code has numerous syntax errors, and there is no recursion here.  If you fix the syntax errors and provide the actual recursive code, we might be able to help you, but in this current form there is no possible way we can assist you.

Comment: ...Now I just have no idea what I'm trying to do...Can anyone just explain recursion instead please?

Comment: @user2344868 Recursion is when a function calls itself, that is all there is to it. But that probably still doesn't help you with your problem. If you have problems with basic Java, there is a tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Comment: I suggest you start by learning how to write code which compiles, before you try to advance to topics like recursion.  Note: Three are more optimal solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you meant was perhaps

```
int myFactorial(int C) {

    int n = Integer.parseInt(objectsChooseField.getText());
    int r = Integer.parseInt(chooseFromField.getText());

    if (C == 1){
       return 1; 
    }
    return (C*(myFactorial(n!/(r!(n-r)))));
    //C(n,r) = n!/(r!(n-r));    
}
```

This is recursive -- The `myFactorial` method calls itself.  Critical to a valid recursive implementation is the check for some terminating condition (the `if (C == 1)` in your case), so that you don't get "infinite" recursion and a nasty crash message.

(But note that this particular implementation is unlikely to work because you're doing integer arithmetic and because `!/` is not a valid operator in Java.)